# How to get the correct point system for an SVG using a SVG software?

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js

I was going through the following example in anime.js:

**[SVG points animation](http://animejs.com/documentation/#svgAttributes)**

When you look at the javascript code that is used to manipulate the SVG, see below:

```
var svgAttributes = anime({
  targets: '#svgAttributes polygon',
  points: '64 128 8.574 96 8.574 32 64 0 119.426 32 119.426 96',
  easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
});
```

The points attributes used here are quite unusual ::- points: `'64 128 8.574 96 8.574 32 64 0 119.426 32 119.426 96',`.

Now i wanted the polygon to transform into 3 dots so , i made the following SVG::-

```
<svg
               xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
               xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
               xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
               xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
               xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
               xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
               width="51.444923mm"
               height="9.6765842mm"
               viewBox="0 0 182.28516 34.287109"
               id="svg2"
               version="1.1"
               inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
               sodipodi:docname="dots.svg">
              <defs
                 id="defs4" />
              <sodipodi:namedview
                 id="base"
                 pagecolor="#ffffff"
                 bordercolor="#666666"
                 borderopacity="1.0"
                 inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
                 inkscape:pageshadow="2"
                 inkscape:zoom="1.4"
                 inkscape:cx="166.57587"
                 inkscape:cy="22.857941"
                 inkscape:document-units="px"
                 inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
                 showgrid="false"
                 inkscape:window-width="1366"
                 inkscape:window-height="705"
                 inkscape:window-x="-8"
                 inkscape:window-y="-8"
                 inkscape:window-maximized="1"
                 fit-margin-top="0"
                 fit-margin-left="0"
                 fit-margin-right="0"
                 fit-margin-bottom="0" />
              <metadata
                 id="metadata7">
                <rdf:RDF>
                  <cc:Work
                     rdf:about="">
                    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                    <dc:type
                       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                    <dc:title></dc:title>
                  </cc:Work>
                </rdf:RDF>
              </metadata>
              <g
                 inkscape:label="Layer 1"
                 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
                 id="layer1"
                 transform="translate(-105.71484,-435.21875)">
                <path
                   id="path4146"
                   transform="translate(148,0)"
                   style="opacity:1;fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                   d="m 122.85742,435.21875 a 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 -17.14258,17.14258 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 17.14258,17.14453 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 140,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 122.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,0 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 31.71484,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,469.50586 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 66,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,34.28711 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -42.28516,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,435.21875 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -8,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,469.50586 Z"
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              </g>
            </svg>
```

So basically the 3 dots are just the following points:

```
<path
                   id="path4146"
                   transform="translate(148,0)"
                   style="opacity:1;fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                   d="m 122.85742,435.21875 a 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 -17.14258,17.14258 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 17.14258,17.14453 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 140,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 122.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,0 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 31.71484,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,469.50586 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 66,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,34.28711 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -42.28516,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,435.21875 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -8,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,469.50586 Z"
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

So i copy paste this into my javascript code like so:

```
var svgAttributes = anime({
  targets: '#svgAttributes polygon',
  easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
  duration: 2000,
  points : 'm 122.85742,435.21875 a 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 -17.14258,17.14258 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 17.14258,17.14453 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 140,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 122.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,0 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 31.71484,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,469.50586 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 66,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,34.28711 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -42.28516,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,435.21875 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -8,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,469.50586 Z'
});
```

But this does't seem to  work , Why ? i notice the points used in the demo use only numbers , where as the points i get using a svg software like inkscape give me points with alphabets in it too , see below:

Points used in anime.js:

```
points="64 128 8.574 96 8.573999999999998 32 64 0 119.426 32 119.426 96"
```

Points i get using a SVG software line inskscape:

```
  points : 'm 122.85742,435.21875 a 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 -17.14258,17.14258 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 17.14258,17.14453 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 140,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 122.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,0 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 31.71484,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,469.50586 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 66,452.36133 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 0 48.85742,435.21875 Z m -74,34.28711 A 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -42.28516,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,435.21875 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -8,452.36328 17.142857,17.142857 0 0 1 -25.14258,469.50586 Z'
```

What am i doing wrong here and how to i get the polygon to  transform into dots ? Also can somebody answer the broader question of how do i go about getting the correct points system like  the one used in anime.js demos ?

Comment: One's a path, the other is a polygon. They are two different kinds of object.

Comment: You should read up on the difference between a [`<polygon>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#shapes-PolygonElement) (which is what the demo uses) and a [`<path>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#paths-PathElement) (which you are trying to use).